# define function type with or without parameters

Tags: typescript, types

How can define function type with which include function with or without parameters?

```js
let param = 'test';

function main(callback: `some type`): void {
  if (need param) {
    callback(param);
  } else {
    callback();
  }
}

function func1():void {
 //
}


function func(param: string):void {
 //
}

main(func1);
main(func2);
```

#### hint:

- callback function param are not part of my main function param and callback function param are variables that's defined where main function defined!
- Each function may be in a separate file

With respect

Comment: It would be a little more respectful to read [the existing documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html).

Comment: no @bradcush, type of func1 is () => void

Comment: Thanks but I could not solve my problem! @jonrsharpe

Comment: That documentation absolutely explains how to define function types of various kinds, so I find that hard to believe. At the very least I'd expect an [mre] showing how _specifically_ you tried to define that (`some type` absolutely doesn't count) and explaining the problem with it.

Comment: It's almost true it just needs to change to ‍‍`(() => void) | ((param: string) => void)` @bradcush

Comment: The only way I know in JS to probe how many params a function wants is to examine its `length`, but this is fragile and not modeled in TS (see [ms/TS#18422](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18422)). You can write a [user-defined type guard function](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) like [this](//tsplay.dev/wQVnnN). But a more TS-friendly approach is to just call `callback(param)` regardless, since zero-arg functions accept extra args, like [this](//tsplay.dev/NDkp1w). Does that address your question, or am I missing something?

Comment: that work!, thank you. Would you like to provide it as an answer? @jcalz

Comment: You are absolutely right
But after a day of trying, I could not succeed
So here I am asking @jonrsharpe

Comment: I will be happy to write up an answer when I get a chance, might be a few hours from now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it seems like you want `callback` to be of the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `(() => void) | ((x: string) => void)`.  That is, it is *either* a function that needs no parameters, *or* a function that needs one `string`-valued parameter.

---

In order for your `(need param)` pseudocode to work, we'd need a runtime check for the list of parameters a function expects. The only thing close to this I know of is [the `Function.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) property which is the *number* of parameters the function requires:

```
function func0(): void {
    console.log("no param needed")
}
console.log(func0.length) // 0

function func1(param: string): void {
    console.log("I got my param and it was " + param.toUpperCase())
}
console.log(func1.length) // 1
```

Note that [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) don't add to the length:

```
function funcRest(...args: string[]) { }
console.log(funcRest.length) // 0
```

Nor do any [optional parameters with a default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters):

```
function funcOpt(x = "hey") { }
console.log(funcOpt.length) // 0
```

But this is complicated by the fact that not all JS runtimes accept rest or default parameters, so if you [target](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#target) an older runtime like ES5, then some of these will be [downleveled](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#downleveling) to a function of a different `length`:

```
// --target=es5
function funcOpt(x = "hey") { }
console.log(funcOpt.length) // 1 instead of 0
```

This makes `Function.length` hard to model consistently in TypeScript, and so TypeScript only gives it a value of type `number` and not a numeric [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  See [microsoft/TypeScript#18422](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18422) for more information.

And that means you can't just check `callback.length === 0` or `callback.length === 1` inside the function and have the compiler understand what you're doing.  If you'd like that check to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type of `callback` to just `()=>void` or just `(x: string)=>void` then you'll have to write a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to tell the compiler that's what it does.

Like this:

```
function needsNoParam(x: Function): x is () => void {
    return x.length === 0;
}

function main(callback: ((x: string) => void) | (() => void)): void {
    if (!needsNoParam(callback)) {
        callback(param); // okay
    } else {
        callback(); // okay
    }
}
```

That compiles with no errors, and it behaves as expected:

```
main(func0); // no param needed
main(func1); // I got my param and it was TEST
```

So that works, but you're sort of fighting against TypeScript to get it done.

---

Still, there is an easier approach that works with TypeScript instead of fighting against it.  TypeScript will allow a function with fewer parameters to be assigned to a variable which expects more parameters (of the same types).  See [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters) for more information.

What I mean is, even though you can't just call `func0("oopsie")` directly:

```
func0("oops") // error, expected 0 arguments but got 1
```

The compiler will let you assign `func0` to a variable of type `(x: string) => void`:

```
const func1a: (x: string) => void = func0; // okay
```

And therefore call it with that extra parameter (through the new variable, at least):

```
func1a("okay") // okay
```

TypeScript takes the position that a well-written function will just ignore extra parameters passed to it, and so it is safe to let this happen, especially for callbacks.   That might seem odd, but the alternative would be very annoying:

For example, when you write `[1, 2, 3].map(x => x+1)` you don't want the compiler to yell at you that `x => x+1` doesn't match the expected `callbackFn` parameter to [the `Array.prototype.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map); `callbackFn` will be called with *three* arguments: the array element, the array index, and the array itself.  The callback `x => x+1` only cares about the array element.  Imagine if you had to write `[1, 2, 3].map((x, i, a) => x+1)` with completely unused `i` and `a` parameters in order to appease the compiler.

So *that* means you really don't need to spend any effort worrying about the difference between `(x: string)=>void` and `()=>void`.  Just treat them both as `(x: string)=>void` and pass in `param` all the time:

```
function main(callback: (x: string) => void) {
    callback(param);
}      

main(func0); // okay, no param needed
main(func1); // okay I got my param and it was TEST
```

That's a lot easier.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-geLwAUQAygBWdggqo1SGPGc6XH3HXbEiDy-AMeqAU3mvK1XqzUP3V9Q8Y1TSQUhj1IdgilYUBIFgBBkFsCAjUwExtSgABBKAoHwFJQEaXhSA0ABZJcIDQ8AvDYQdeAEADxCkGR5DrcFtFfQ4rladprCQbpU36KZYWzQdviOa5bgfR5B2giJeQbSFoQWOEvmHX0FRxa1H0JYhiU9LgZKUBwoUxDQNBgKA+xrTAMCXBcIAsKg1BILldQwFJaEgYA+C8RpaAEX8kFDQcCwEQUQG4lNxUEmYO0hORbw0FpV0HMKsUS1dLM5dLyBYiNBWFbVItSCUYvCBEfSLeklRVNVKn-fE9QNECzUtTTbXtR1MFddAPWk88X2qN9r3imsNIAp9iAGq8HE-EbOR-WqNU0wCmqQE0vHAo9IKgoA)

Comment: I'm surprised by your complete answer
I wish I could somehow repay your kindness :)

Comment: What if the callback type is `(...param: string[]) => void`? [based on Shahriar Shojib anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72080257/18004491)

Comment: Since that wasn't part of your question as asked, I'm not sure what to say.  Is this a followup question?  If the callback type is `(...x: string[])=>void`, such as `main((...args: string[]) => console.log(args));` then it needs no parameters and will not be passed any in the user-defined type guard version, but it will be passed `param` in the second version because it does accept a string argument.

Comment: It was not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Typescript provides a utility function to extract function type arguments into a tuple.
With this, it won't be a problem if the callbacks have optional parameters or no parameters at all.

```
let param = 'test';

function main(callback: (...pram: string[]) => void):void {
  callback(param);
}

function func0():void {
 
}


function func1(param: string):void {
 //
}

main(func0);
main(func1);
```

Comment: But part of my question is how to tell if the input parameter function wants it or not؟